# How do I scale up everything on my display?

Tags: linux-mint, display, display-settings

I'm pretty new to Linux (running linux mint). I've been messing around with the display resolution and changed it from 1280x720 to 1920x1080. All the icons and taskbar are pretty small. I want to scale everything up, not just the font size. How do I do this? Thanks!

If this helps: I think I'm looking for the linux equivalent of this on windows (image below):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is for the MATE version :**

*Fonts:*
    Click 'Menu', type  'Apparence' and click, select tab : Polices ,  then update font and/or size as needed.

*Desktop icons size:*
    Right click the icon, there is a 'Resize icon' entry, drag the icon's corner.